# camera overlay messes up the photo

Tags: camera, overlay, titanium, titanium-mobile

so I tried to create a simple overlay for the camera view now the images are coming out distorted

```
var cameraOverlay = Titanium.UI.createView({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    right: 0,
});
cameraOverlayButton = Titanium.UI.createView({
    right: 0
});
cameraOverlayButtonImage = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image: 'buttons/camera_64.png',
    center: {x: '50%', y: '50%'},
});
cameraOverlayButton.add(cameraOverlayButtonImage);
cameraOverlay.add(cameraOverlayButton);
cameraOverlayButtonImage.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.Media.takePicture();
});



Titanium.Media.showCamera({
            overlay: cameraOverlay,
            transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().scale(1),
            success: processImage,
            cancel: function(){return false;},
            error: imageFailed,

            mediaTypes:Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO,
        });
```

am I doing anything wrong? or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely stemmed from the transformation. Try removing the `transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().scale(1)` property and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks but that didn't help... I had put that there because I read somewhere that it would fix the problem... I'm starting to think this is just a bug or the documentation shouldn't say it's supported on android...